# PowerShell - parallel threads all running on same CPU core

Tags: .net, multithreading, powershell

I'm writing a multithreaded PowerShell script to devide a rather long lasting task into several threads.
My problem is, that all threads are running on the same CPU core (12 are available) when the Shell.Application-ComObject is involved. I need it to collect the titles of all documents in a specific folder (GetDetailsOf()-method). Sadly this particular method takes a little when applied to a couple of hundred or more files at once which is the actual motivation to parallelize this whole script.

Simplified code:

```
$NumCores = $env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
$URL = "C:\Windows\System32"

$ThreadCode = {
    param([UInt32] $CoreAffinity, [Object[]] $FileInfos, [Object] $ShellFolder, [System.Collections.Hashtable] $CTXTable)
    
    #Set CPU-Affinity first - NOT WORKING YET
    $Signature = '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern UIntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread,UIntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);'
    $Affinator = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Win32SetThreadAffinityMask" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
    
    #$Affinator::SetThreadAffinityMask(<#HANDLE???#>, [System.UIntPtr]::new($CoreAffinity))
    
    $Count = $FileInfos.Count
    $DataArray = [System.Object[]]::new($Count)
    #$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
    #$ShellFolder = $Shell.NameSpace("C:\Windows\System32")

    #The following loop only runs on one cpu core
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Count; $i++)
    {
        $FI = $FileInfos[$i]
        
        $ShellFile = $ShellFolder.ParseName($FI.Name)
        $Title = $ShellFolder.GetDetailsOf($ShellFile, 21)

        $DataArray[$i] = @{Fileinfo = $FI; Title = $Title}
        #$DataArray[$i] = @{URL = $FI.FullName; ColumnData = $Columns; Text = $FI.Name; ImageKey = $ImgKey; Tag = @{URL = $FI.FullName; Extension = $Extension; Item = $FI; OpenAsLink = $OpenAsLink}}
    }
    
    #The following loop will run on all cores evenly when activated
    <#
    $j = 0
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt [uint32]::MaxValue; $i++)
    {
        $j++
    }#>
    Write-Information $DataArray
    
    #Finish Thread with some return values through the Information-Stream
    Write-Information ("ManagedThreadId: " + [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
}

$RSP = [RunSpaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $NumCores)
$RSP.ApartmentState = [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::MTA
$RSP.ThreadOptions = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSThreadOptions]::UseNewThread
$RSP.Open()

$PSArray = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumCores; $i++)
{
    [PowerShell]::Create()
}
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$ShellFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($URL)

$DirectoryInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($URL)
$InfoItems = $DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()
$ItemCount = $InfoItems.Count
$ItemsPerThread = [Math]::Floor($InfoItems.Count / $NumCores)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumCores; $i++)
{
    $PSArray[$i].RunSpacePool = $RSP
    $Affinity = [Math]::Pow(2, $i)

    $SubIndexLBound = $i * $ItemsPerThread
    $SubIndexUBound = ($i + 1) * $ItemsPerThread -1
    $SubItems = $InfoItems[$SubIndexLBound..$SubIndexUBound]
    $PSArray[$i].AddScript($ThreadCode).AddArgument($Affinity).AddArgument($SubItems).AddArgument($ShellFolder).AddArgument($null) | Out-Null
}

$AsyncResults = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumCores; $i++)
{
    $PSArray[$i].BeginInvoke()
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumCores; $i++)
{
    $AsyncResults[$i].AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne() | Out-Null
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumCores; $i++)
{
    write-Host "i: $i`tThreadID: $($PSArray[$i].Streams.Information[1].MessageData)"
}
```

Finally I can see that all threads had a different ManagedThreadId but when I keep a look at the task manager all work was done by the same cpu core. But once I un-comment the second for-loop all CPU cores will be used evenly AFTER the first loop where I fetch all document titles.

So I want to force the threads to run on a specific core through "SetThreadAffinityMask" but so far I don't know how to get the handle for the current thread? Is this the correct approach at all or might there be better ways to read meta data from files?

**Solution see comment by @zett42**

`$RSP.ApartmentState` must remain as `[System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA`. Then it works if you instantiate `$Shell` inside the thread.

Comment: This is is more a **.net** related issue then a PowerShell issue. Why not using any of the designated PowerShell [multi-threading cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs) (as `Invoke-Command`, `Start-Process`, `Start-ThreadJob` or `ForEach-Object -Parallel`) for this?

Comment: ForEach-Object -Parallel and Start-ThreadJob only work in PowerShell 7... I need to rely on PowerShell 5 for now.
I don't quiet get behind Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {...} -AsJob because it always tells me it can't resolve the parameters... ?

Comment: Maybe a workflow instead? I know it's the slowest of all threading options, but it's nicely manageable; perhaps may not be what you're after but, throwing out ideas in hopes it might help you.

Comment: I recommend you to open a new question which the actual (script) or [mcve] that you trying to invoke in each thread and your attempt with `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {...} -AsJob`

Comment: AFAIK most shell COM objects [don't support MTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows/win32/shell-functions-multithreaded-apartment). The code might appear to work, but due to synchronization of the COM objects, effectively runs on single core only.

Comment: Have you tried to create `Shell.Application` within each thread, so they don't use a shared instance? Then STA should work.

Comment: Well changing MTA to STA actually worked. -.- Apparently I hadn't tried the combination of STA and instanciating the Shell.Application within my thread yet.