# Using Shell32-interfaces in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, interface, shell32

Question out of curiosity:
When you type "[Shell32." in the PowerShell-ISE it will offer you a couple of interfaces like [Shell32.Shell], [Shell32.FolderItem] etc... Is it possible to use these interfaces e.g. to gather meta information about files like you normally would with the Shell.Application com-object?

I tried to read into interfaces but I don't really get behind the idea of these...

Comment: Can you name an example of the kind of metadata you're interested in?

Comment: These interfaces can't be instanciated directly using `New-Object`, you need some other means like the `Shell.Application` COM-Object or standalone WinAPI functions. The question is somewhat broad, it would be easier to answer when you have a specific problem to solve.

Comment: My actual problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70925059/powershell-parallel-threads-all-running-on-same-cpu-core?noredirect=1#comment125391407_70925059
Multithreading apparently does not work with Shell.Application when using the NameSpace.GetDetailsOf() method so I was looking for alternative ways to use the GetDetailsOf() method without the original Shell.Application com object. I know you can use NameSpace.ParseName("SomeFile.xlsx").ExtendedProperty("{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 2") method but it's much less convenient because you need to know these IDs.